# LINQ Returning Empty Collection Where ForEach Finds A Value

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code.  I've edited the classes somewhat.  I've verified that it all works as expected, only the LINQ fails.

```
public class SANSwitch
{
 public bool HasWWN(string wwn)

     {
        bool test = false;
        if (wwn.StartsWith("55")) { test =    VirtualWWNList.Values.Contains(wwn); }
        else { test= SwitchWWPN.Contains(wwn.Substring(0,20)); }

        return test;
     }
}

 public class SANFabric
{
    // dictionary of switch WWPNs and SANSwitch objects
    public Dictionary<string, SANSwitch> MemberSwitches = new Dictionary<string, SANSwitch>();

    public bool IsFabricMember(string wwn)
    {
        var found = MemberSwitches.Values.Where(t => t.HasWWN(wwn)).ToList();
        if (found.Count() > 0) { return true; }
        else { return false; }
    }
}

List<SANFabric> Fabrics = new List<SANFabric();
string wwn = String.Empty;
 // pretend there's code here and we have a list of fabrics
 // and wwn has been assigned a value
```

Here's what works.  That is when a switch that has a WWN that matches the string is a member of the fabric, tester gets set to true

```
bool tester = false;
        //find out if the switch is a member of the fabric

        {
            foreach (SANFabric f in fabrics)
            {
                tester = f.IsFabricMember(wwn);
            }

        }
```

Here's what doesn't work.  ismember is always empty, even when it's run against the same collection.

```
var ismember = fabrics.Where(t => t.IsFabricMember(wwn));
```

where IsMember() is defined as

```
  public bool IsFabricMember(string wwn)
    {
        var found = MemberSwitches.Values.Where(t => t.HasWWN(wwn)).ToList();
        if (found.Count() > 0) { return true; }
        else { return false; }
    }
```

IsMember() always returns false because found.Count is always 0. I've stepped through the debugger and HasWWN is working correctly.

Comment: The code snippets are not equivalent. Your foreach version returns the result of the last item, the linq query returns a collection where the method returned `true`. What are we supposed to be looking at here?

Comment: so you have a class SANSwitch with one method in it HasWWN and no properties; why not just put that method in the class SANFabric, so you don't have to worry about that you're not sending in parameters, or trying to call some global initiated classes.

Comment: `var found = MemberSwitches.Values.Where(t => t.HasWWN(wwn)).ToList();` maybe where your code is broken. What do you think you are passing ToList()?? its a keyvaluepair that probably (from my limited knowledge) is unable to convert. try this `var found = MemberSwitches.Values.Where(t => t.HasWWN(wwn)).Select(x => x.key).ToList();`

Comment: @JeffMercado  I expect the results of the LINQ query to be all SANFabric instances where  IsMember() returns true.  The ForEach was just to validate that IsMember() is working.  IsMember returns true when it is supposed to.  The LINQ query comes up empty every time.

Comment: @Edward - the ToList() was just to see if I got a different result.  With ToList() not there, it still doesn't work.  A SANFabric doesn't have a WWN. A switch does.  A SANFabric is a network of switches.  IsMember() just checks to see if the SANFabric instances has a member switch with the WWN I am looking for.  IsMenber() works correctly. The LINQ query always returns an empty collection.

Comment: so then almost a tree where switch is the parent and SANFabric is a list of subNodes? Why then is there a method in both classes to make similar checks? Simple is better, less chance at errors.

Comment: No.  SANFabric is the parent.  SANSwitch would be nodes.  It's not really a tree. Its a network of switches.  A programmer might call it a graph.  SANFabric has a method called IsMember. IsMember takes a string as a parameter.  This string is a switch identifier, unique to each switch. The LINQ statement should return the switch that owns that, if the switch is in the MemberSwitches dictionary.  The problem is the LINQ statement always returns empty, even when I know it should return a SANSwitch instance.

Comment: I could get this working with the ForEach.  I want to know why the LINQ query in IsMember() is failing.  found is always empty.

Comment: One unrelated suggestion change on your code. Put the `dictionary<string,SANSwitch>` where you have the `List<SANFabric> Fabrics = new List<SANFabric();`  as `dictionary<string,List<SANSwitch>>` This gives you a collection of your Fabric and all the networks they belong too.

Comment: One thing that is sure is that your code is not efficient because you always create a list just to check if the list is empty or not. You could use `Any` for that purpose.

Comment: Since the code if modified - can you try replacing `SANFabric` in `foreach (SANFabric f in fabrics)` with `var` and/or changing `fabrics.Where(t => t.IsFabricMember(wwn));` to `fabrics.Where(t => (SANFabric)t.IsFabricMember(wwn));`

Comment: It is hard to see what is wrong with your code. Make a compilable example and it would be easier for us to try. Include minimal data too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public bool IsFabricMember(string wwn)
{
    if (MemberSwitches.Where(x => x.Value.HasWWN(wwn)).Count() > 0) 
        return true; 
    else 
        return false; 
}
```

or

```
public bool IsFabricMember(string wwn)
{
    if (MemberSwitches.Any(x => x.Value.HasWWN(wwn))) { return true; }
    else { return false; }
}
```

or

```
public bool IsFabricMember(string wwn)
{
   return MemberSwitches.Any(x => x.Value.HasWWN(wwn));
}
```

Comment: Or simply `return MemberSwitches.Any(x => x.Value.HasWWN(wwn));`

Answer (score 0):

Your code works, based on how I filled up missing pieces.

---

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<SANFabric> Fabrics = new List<SANFabric>() ;
            Dictionary<string,SANSwitch> _swDict=new Dictionary<string,SANSwitch>();
            _swDict.Add("A", new SANSwitch() { SwitchWWPN = new List<string>() { "CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ12333" }, 
                                                VirtualWWNList = new Dictionary<string, string>() { 
                                                                                                    {"ABC","55555555"},
                                                                                                    {"DEF","993383838"}
                                                                                                  } 
                                             }
                                             );

            _swDict.Add("B", new SANSwitch()
                                            {
                                                SwitchWWPN = new List<string>() { "KGBIFBGKLMPQUERREE", "CDEFGHIKGBIFBGKLMPQUERREEXYZ12333" },
                                                VirtualWWNList = new Dictionary<string, string>() { 
                                                                                                                                    {"GHI","8888383"},
                                                                                                                                    {"JKL","00933939"}
                                                                                                                                  }
                                            });

            Fabrics.Add(new SANFabric()
            {
                MemberSwitches = _swDict
            });

            var f1 = Fabrics.Where(t => t.IsFabricMember("55555555")).ToList();
            var f2 = Fabrics.Where(t => t.IsFabricMember("CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUV")).ToList();
            Console.WriteLine("# of items to be member: {0},{1}",f1.Count,f2.Count);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    public class SANSwitch
    {        
        public Dictionary<string,string> VirtualWWNList {get;set;}

        public List<string> SwitchWWPN {get;set;}

        public bool HasWWN(string wwn)
        {
            bool test = false;
            if (wwn.StartsWith("55")) { test = VirtualWWNList.Values.Contains(wwn); }
            else { test = SwitchWWPN.Contains(wwn.Substring(0, 20)); }

            return test;
        }
    }

    public class SANFabric
    {
        // dictionary of switch WWPNs and SANSwitch objects
        public Dictionary<string, SANSwitch> MemberSwitches { get; set; }

        public bool IsFabricMember(string wwn)
        {
            var found = MemberSwitches.Values.Where(t => t.HasWWN(wwn)).ToList();
            if (found.Count() > 0) { return true; }
            else { return false; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks. I copied that and tried it, it works.  It doesn't work in my original code.  I still don't know why.  I went with Edward's second answer below to return Any SANSwitch.